# Can an Azure "group" be used as Azure Sql Database's "Active Directory Admin"?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, ssms

**Azure SQL Database** lets you set a user as an Active Directory Admin. This allows you to log into the database using your microsoft account credentials. I would like to use an **Azure security group** instead of a single user so that multiple people in our domain can be Azure SQL DB admins.

I've tried creating an Azure security group "TestGroup" and using it in the Azure configuration. I can successfully set "TestGroup" as the Active Direcory Admin in the Azure portal for the DB, but when I try to log into the DB using SQL Server Management Studio, it doesn't let me in. I confirmed my user is in this group.

This is the error it returns:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what you described you did assign the Active Directory admin as group correctly.

I suspect that your problem lies with the logging in method, in order to log in by AAD, you need to select "**Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA**" option, and under user name provide email from within the AAD security group. Then the azure login window should pop up.

[image]

Comment: I did use this Authentication method and that's when the error popped up.

Comment: Then you probably didn't specify the exact database to connect to, you can do this selecting Options >> Connection properties

Answer (score 0):

Azure "groups" can be used as "Active Directory administrators" for Azure Sql databases.

> When using Azure Active Directory authentication, put Azure Active
>   Directory users into an Azure Active Directory security group. Create
>   a contained database user for the group. Place one or more database
>   users into a custom database role with specific permissions
>   appropriate to that group of users.
>
> When using SQL authentication, create contained database users in the
>   database. Place one or more database users into a custom database role
>   with specific permissions appropriate to that group of users.

I hope this article will help you   [here](https://colinsalmcorner.com/configuring-aad-authentication-to-azure-sql-databases/).